# How to get resources from WEB-INF from Spring java configuration @Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I am trying to load specific resource under `WEB-INF` directory during `@Bean` creation in one of the Spring `@Configuration` classes.

As I know `@ImportResource` is used only for Spring xml configurations and not for other files.
Approaches with `ClassLoader` don't work and always return `null`.

For example:

```
    @Bean
    public aBean someBean() {
        final URL someFolderDirUrl = WebConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/someFolder");
        final URL someFolderDirUrl2 = WebConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/someFolder");
        final URL someFolderDirUrl3 = WebConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/WEB-INF/someFolder");
        final URL someFolderDirUrl4 = WebConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("someFolder");

        // final URI someFolderDirUri = new URI("file:/WEB-INF/someFolder");

        if(modulesDirUrl != null) {
            File someFolderDirFile;
            try {
                someFolderDirFile = new File(someFolderDirUrl.toURI());
            } catch(final URISyntaxException e) {
                someFolderDirFile = new File(someFolderDirUrl.getPath());
            }

            return new aBean(someFolderDirFile);
        }

        return new aBean();
    }
```

At the end all **someFolderDirUrlX** variables are `null`, the same for `someFolderDirUri`.

Is it possible to get a `File` object inside Spring's `@Configuration` class which points to file or directory inside `WEB-INF`?

Comment: Inject a `ResourceLoader` to utilize Spring's resource loading mechanism instead of hacking around yourself.

Comment: Not with the `ClassLoader`. `getResource` is meant for a classpath resource. `WEB-INF` is not typically put on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access this from the ServletContext:

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

@Bean
public aBean someBean() {
     File someFolderDirUrl = new File( servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/") );
     ....
}
```