# importing XML config into java config based (annotation) project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

I'm working on Spring MVC annotation based application. I have web.xml file entry as follows (using WebConfig.java for configuration):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sdsdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.conf.WebConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>            

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now when I try to integrate security related XML file I'm facing following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:638)

I tried to import xml file as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.stk.controller")
@ImportResource({"securityContext.xml"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Screenshot

[image]
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/BosWG.jpg

Comment: You can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014919/converting-spring-xml-file-to-spring-configuration-class/24014920#24014920 TL;DR: use `@ImportResource`

Comment: Did you find a solution because I have the same problem. My file is under `WEB-INF/spring/security-context.xml` Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add classpath as shown below, provided its in classpath

```
@ImportResource("classpath:securityContext.xml")
```

If you have multiple configuration files then

```
@ImportResource(locations={"classpath:securityContext.xml","file://c:/test-config.xml"})
```

You can access the file from WEB-INF directory using

```
@ImportResource("file:**/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml")
```

However I would recommend you to move configuration file to src/main/resource directory and use the file line that is loading file using classpath. These files will be copied to `WEB-INF/classes` directory during packing of war by maven  which is classpath

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested but nothing worked for me. Please note , I have kept securityContext.xml file inside WEB-INF folder (at web.xml level)

Comment: Did you try @ImportResource("/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml")

Comment: yes. I tried all possible ways to add resource via @ ImportResources but nothing worked. Please find image for project structure.

Comment: Add this @ImportResource("file:**/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml") it works

Comment: which step you followed? file stuff or as I suggested to move file to src/main/resources directory

Comment: Can't load from `WEB-INF` directly via `@ImportResource`. Take a look at these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39998621/156973 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/25936535/156973