# Importing resources under WEB-INF directory of a war file to applicationContext file using Spring

Tags: spring

I am using Spring framework in my project. I want to import all the xml resources/files under `/WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/` directory of a war file in the applicationContext configuration file. I tried with the following lines of code, but not working.

```
<import resource= /WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

<import resource="file:**/WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

<import resource="file:///WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

<import resource="file:WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>
```

Any ideas on how to load from WEB-INF of war file using Spring?

Comment: Remove `file:`...

Comment: @ M. Deinum I have already tried with `<import resource= /WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>`. You mean to say like this? ` <import resource="**/WEB-INF/CustomerService/spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>`

Comment: @M. Deinum Any other thoughts? Please let me know if you require any additional info.

Comment: No... without the leading  `*`. And possibly even without `/WEB-INF` ...

Comment: @M. Deinum , That didn't worked.. :(

Comment: From which file are yu importing this, and how is that file being loaded.

Comment: Actually I am importing from a  file which is in turn  imported in the applicationContext file. This applicationContext file is imported from web.xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WEB-INF directory path will not be available as classpath in the standalone Spring project. So, I have moved the configuration files to `src/resources` folder to import them without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use classpath to import another XML configuration file. Like this:

```
<import resource="classpath:your_config.xml"/>
```

Assuming that the requested configuration file is located within your classpath